# Can Great Plains + Smartconnect integrate with cXML files?

Tags: dynamics-gp, cxml

I need to upload data from cXML files to Great Plains system. We use SmartConnect for GP tool to integrate data into Dynamics GP. Is this integration possible?

Answer (score 0):

An integration like this is typically designed and scheduled through a tool called Integration Manager.  This tool allows you to map custom XML or tables into GP through DTS-like routines. For more information on it's uses, you can find the user manual here: http://mbs.microsoft.com/downloads/public/GP90Docs/IMUsersGuide.pdf